# How to change the favicon icon in spfx sharepoint react page

Tags: sharepoint, favicon

I am trying to change the favicon icon in sharepoint react project but the solutions i am getting are pure sharepoint not using react with sharepoint

https://kirtiprajapati.com/2019/01/10/spfx-application-customizer-how-to-change-favicon-on-modern-sharepoint-sites/
tried this artical wont working
there is not html file like react have to change favicon icon
https://kirtiprajapati.com/2019/01/10/spfx-application-customizer-how-to-change-favicon-on-modern-sharepoint-sites/
wast of time

Comment: You should be able to add HTML/TypeScript code in SPFx solution even if you are using the SPFx application customizer + react solution.